# Finding the length of a segment that is part of the midline of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

In a trapezoid, the midline, which is the line through the non-parallel sides, intersects the diagonal at P and Q. Find PQ if the parallel sides have lengths 6 and 20.

I know that the midline length is half the sum of the lengths of the parallel sides giving 13. I am confused on how 7 is the answer and what concept should I know to find PQ here. Does anybody know a technique when solving this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let the midline cuts non-parallel sides at M and N.

$MP=NQ=\frac{6}{2}=3$ (midpoint theorem)

$MN=\frac{6+20}{2}=13$

$PQ=13-2\times 3=7$